# Can we define ink_e2e tests outside of contracts module?

Tags: ink, smart-contract, testing

devs. I am writing the e2e tests for my smart contracts using `ink_e2e`
In contracts, I define the e2e-tests like this.

```rust
#[openbrush::contract]
pub mod controller {
    ...
    
    #[cfg(all(test, feature = "e2e-tests"))]
    mod e2e_tests {
    }
}
```

But I want to define tests like this.

```rust
#[cfg(all(test, feature = "e2e-tests"))]
mod e2e_tests {}

#[openbrush::contract]
pub mod controller {
    ...
}
```

In this case, I have noticed that `e2e-tests` feature is disabled.
Anybody met this issue and solved it?

Comment: May be if you can follow this [PR](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/issues/1692) in order to resolve this.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But It is still disabled.
`code is inactive due to #[cfg] directives: feature = "e2e-tests" is disabled`

Answer (score 0):

```
#[cfg(all(test, feature = "e2e-tests"))]
mod e2e_tests {}

#[openbrush::contract]
pub mod controller {
    ...
}
```

This should work.

The tests should run with usual `cargo test --features e2e-tests`